# How to create a login and set check policy as off in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I am using PowerShell to create a login in Azure SQL, but I am running into an issue of not being able to set the check policy flag as off. I am changing databases from SQL Server to Azure SQL where in SQL Server this query was allowed.

Here is an example of my PowerShell method that calls `invoke-sqlcmd`:

```
Run-powershellsqlcmd `
            -Server $DbHost -InstanceName $DbInstanceName -Port $DbPort `
            -Username $CreationUsername -Password $CreationPassword `
            -Query "CREATE LOGIN $(Get-Parameter $UserKey) WITH PASSWORD = N'$(Get-Parameter $PassKey)', CHECK_POLICY= OFF" `
            Out-Null
```

When I run this, I get an error

> Keyword or statement option 'check_policy' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Is there any way to turn `check_policy` off when creating an Azure SQL login?

Comment: doesn't look like it :/ What kind of policy are you looking to avoid?

Comment: No, `CHECK_POLICY` applies to the _Windows_ password complexity policy, and you can’t choose to bypass this in Azure SQL Database. Notice how it’s missing from the option list in the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true). Use a stronger password or use a different authentication method.

Comment: @siggemannen I am actually fine with the password policy being turned on now. Do you guys know if the password has an expiration? If so I would like to by pass that, I am aware that azure sql does not support Check_Expiration as well

Comment: from what i can see, passwords don't expire: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=azuresqldb-current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017#policy-enforcement) check policy is only applicable to local sql server it does not support for Azure sql server and azure sql database.

[image]

So you could not set  `CHECK_POLICY = ON or OFF`.